Does the UN treat Palestinian refugees differently from other refugees?
The FDD makes the following claim...

The United Nations (UN) treats Palestinian refugees differently than
refugees from every other conflict or circumstance. Specifically,
UNRWA automatically registers the descendants of Palestinian refugees
in perpetuity, which has led to explosive growth in its official
number of clients

It goes on to claim that Mike Pompeo, then US Secretary of State, stated in 2001:

fewer than 5 percent of UNRWA-registered “refugees” meet the criteria
for the designation that the UN applies to refugees from other
conflicts.

And yet the UN website states all refugees are treated the same...

the children of refugees and their descendants are also considered
refugees

Does the UN treat Palestinian refugees differently from all other refugee groups?

The paragraph goes on to say, "In 2021, then Secretary of State Mike Pompeo stated that fewer than 5 percent of UNRWA-registered “refugees” meet the criteria for the designation that the UN applies to refugees from other conflicts. By growing the refugee population and promoting Palestinian claims to Israeli land, UNRWA perpetuates and exacerbates the conflict." Isn't this biased?

Question has been answered on politics.SE.

@GaslightDeceiveSubvert - that's quite an old thread, also it starts with the statement that they ARE treated differently. I'm trying to understand the current situation

Right, but the answer to your question is "no". It may be useful to whoever answers this question to consult what has written before about this subject. FDD is as you perhaps know a neoconservative think tank with a less than stellar reputation.

@GaslightDeceiveSubvert - you may be correct, but I was hoping for an answer more recent than 9 years old, and slight more detailed than "no" ;-)

I suppose you could focus on the middle claim/quote. That they are "treated differently" because the UNRWA rather then the UNHCR deals with them is rather well known, and rather boring/bureaucratic answer in itself.

The Geneva Convention of July 28, 1951 relating to the status of refugees, is not applicable "to those refugees who benefit from the protection or assistance of a United Nations agency other than UNHCR”. In other words, people benefiting from UNRWA assistance do not fall within the scope of this convention.

I think this post could use a little more information in the body. Does fdd cite any sources or original reporting?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

FDD doesn't claim that fewer than 5% of Palestinian refugees meet the criteria for the designation that the UN applies to refugees from other conflicts; they report that Mike Pompeo made this claim. But they link to a tweet that makes a much vaguer claim unrelated to any official criteria: "most others are not refugees by any rational criteria." There's a big difference between 95% and "most" and between "criteria that the UN applies to refugees from other conflicts" and "any rational criteria." To evaluate the claim, it would be helpful to know which Convention criteria are allegedly not met.

@phoog The second claim is indeed awkwardly second-hand - the linked tweet doesn't contain the quote, and the link from there is dead (I haven't tried looking for archived copies). The first claim seems quite specific though; it even says "specifically". I've edited some caveat to the second quote, but I'm actually wondering if it should just be deleted, to avoid the distraction.

@inund8 Claims in questions don't need to be well referenced, only notable, and sufficiently well-defined to answer. A newspaper headline pulling a statistic out of thin air would be a good fit for this site, for instance, and it would not be up to the question to track down the newspaper's sources, that's the job of the answers.
